# combining two jquery functions for slider

Tags: jquery, function

hey I have two functions, I have a slider with some deep linking.  There is a carousel that pairs up with the slider and when the slider moves to the next slide the event prompts the carousel to move to the next slide and switch classes.  The problem is when you load the page with the deep link there is no event, so it doesn't highlight a thumb, so I have two seperate functions, they seem repetitive and I was wondering if there was a way to combine them?

```
$(function() {
    if(portfolio_slide_TOTAL.currSlideId == 4) {
        // your code here!
        $('#portfolio_carousel_thumbs').data('touchCarousel').goTo(4);
        $("#color_goto").addClass("library_thumb_active");
    }
});
$(function() {
    portfolio_slide_TOTAL.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function() {
        if(portfolio_slide_TOTAL.currSlideId == 4) {
            // your code here!
            $('#portfolio_carousel_thumbs').data('touchCarousel').goTo(4);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
$(function() {
    var flag=true;
    test_slide(); //runs first

    portfolio_slide_TOTAL.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', test_slide);

    function test_slide() {
        if(portfolio_slide_TOTAL.currSlideId == 4) {
            // your code here!
            $('#portfolio_carousel_thumbs').data('touchCarousel').goTo(4);
            if (flag) {
                $("#color_goto").addClass("library_thumb_active"); //only on first
                flag=false; //set flag to false after first run
            }
        }

    }
});    ​
```

Comment: bam! that works, awesome.  Can you explain to me what exactly the flag is doing?

Comment: The flag is set to `true`, but on the first time the `test_slide` function runs it's set to `false` instead. Then on the next time the `test_slide` function runs, which will be when the custom `rsAfterSlideChange` event is triggered, the flag is already set to `false`, and the `addClass` will not be performed, as it only runs the first time. Looking at it now, it would be better to change the flag only if it's true, I'll edit that in the answer now !